# WSE2 to WCF: Signing a SOAP message

Tags: wcf, wse

I need to covert code from WSE2 to WCF and need a few tips on how to implement signing a SOAP message with a X509Certificate2 object.

WSE2 code:

```
X509SecurityToken tok = new X509SecurityToken(cert);
SoapContext cont = cfs.RequestSoapContext;
cont.Security.Tokens.Add(tok);
cont.Security.Elements.Add(new MessageSignature(tok));
```

"cert" is my X509Certificate2 object and "cfs" is my Web Services client object.

How can I make this work without WSE2, how to do the same in WCF?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom binding for that, but first you must figure out which kind of binding you need. Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa751836(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.servicemodel.messagesecurityversion(v=vs.110).aspx). On custom binding you can add security token for signing. My asymmetric binding looks like this: (but you can also use symmetric binding)

```
AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement asymmetricBinding = SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateDuplexBindingElement(
                MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10);
        asymmetricBinding.InitiatorTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters
        {
            InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient
        };
        asymmetricBinding.RecipientTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters
        {
            InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never
        };
        asymmetricBinding.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.SignedEncrypted.Add(new UserNameSecurityTokenParameters
        {
            InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient
        });
        asymmetricBinding.IncludeTimestamp = true;
        asymmetricBinding.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Strict;
        asymmetricBinding.MessageProtectionOrder = MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt;

        var textMessageEncoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8));
        var httpsTransport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();

        CustomBinding b = new CustomBinding(asymmetricBinding, textMessageEncoding, httpsTransport);
```

Then you can set certificates on ClientCredentials of the EndpointClient

```
var wsClient = new YourEndpointClient(b, new EndpointAddress(yourWsEndPointAddress));
wsClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(cert);
wsClient.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = new X509Certificate2(cert);
```